# In Microsoft Security Essentials how do you see the location of the detected threat?

Tags: anti-virus, ms-security-essentials

MSE pops up saying the detected item, alert level, status and recommended action but doesn't say where the detected item is located. How do you find out? For example if it's in something I just downloaded I'd like to know so I don't re download it again or distribute further vs a file is infected in a temporary files folder for IE.